# Set value to page Django

Tags: django, django-cms

Hi everyone what is the best way to solvent this problem...

I create a app in my django CMS, I create a AppHook with this app, and now I can choose in multiples pages.

I need to use in two different page, en my app looks like this...

[image]

The select have two options, depends that the option that I choose,show one thing or other thing.

when I click in `update bottom` I call a URL, the problem is that this URL is different for each page and option so

```
page1 has
 option1 => url1
 option2 => url2

page2
  option1 => url3
  Option2 => url4
```

I think the solution is, I have to associate each link with each page.

But what is the best way to do that...

1.- It is posible when I associate the app to page create a text input to set the value of URL.

2.- Or extending the page and create a text input there to set the value. In this case is posible show this new text input for only this 2 page that needed.

3.- Management the app from admin, and associates a page with the URL.

4.- Other option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue using this  [Aldryn Apphooks Config](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/namespaced_apphooks.html#an-example-apphook-configuration)